# Is it possible to reference columns from one common table expression in another, without using joins?

Tags: sql, common-table-expression

I have a legacy system in which the data are loaded in a tree structure (displayed later as a tree view) using a "multilevel set of queries". That is, each level has its own query. The lower levels depend on the data retrieved by the upper level. Basically, the parameters for the lower level queries are (some of) the values returned by the upper level ones. I am able to retrieve the queries but I want to build one "general" query using the "with" statement. The question is: how do I reference the upper level CTE in the lower level ones, without modifying the queries by using joins?

Here is a simplified example of what I would like to have:

```
with Level1Q as (select * from table1),
Level2Q as (select * from table2 where id=Level1Q.id)
select * from Level2Q
```

I can access each query individually as they are stored in an XML file, which differs from user to user: `select * from table1` & `select * from table2 where id=:param1`. I have already the routines that "fill" the parameters but I don't want to change the existing query text by inserting joins, because that implies a relative complicated process of parsing SQL syntax.

This is what I know it works and try to avoid:

```
with Level1Q as (select * from table1),
Level2Q as (select t2.* from table2 t2, Level1Q l1 where t2.id=l1.id)
select * from Level2Q
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve here. Do you want to build one query which could be used for all levels? How would the query know which level is it run for?

Comment: I want to build a query that comprises all the queries, for all the levels. I can create for each CTE a level specific name (as `Level1Q` or `Level2Q`) and then call the specific CTE associated with the current tree level. The query does not need to know about the level. That is something that I'm aware of and can dynamically add the name of the target CTE at the end of the query.

Comment: I'm agree with Quassnoi here. You have to specify your task more clearly. I can imagine 2 approaches to tree precession - recursive cte or some kind of iterative recursive loop. In your Level2Q cte you can see Level1Q cte, but it's relation, not parameter

Comment: @AndreiV your task really looks like case for recursive common table expression

Comment: @AndreiV: could you please post a real-world example? What would you tree look like on a root level and on level 2?

Comment: To me, it sounds like "I have N user-defined queries, they can and must be run in sequence, I want to *dynamically* build and run a (cte) query from these to generate data at level X where 1 <= X <= N". Is that the idea?

Comment: @Quassnoi I think among all the details of my specific problem, the question has become unclear. Sorry about that! Please forget about the tree. Just consider that I have a file from which I read sql queries. These queries are chained in a specific order. I cannot, at this moment, change the text of the queries, except the `:param`sections. Consider the next example: in the file I have two queries `select * from users where name=:param_user` and `select * from projects where id=:param_id`. The second query needs the id selected by the first. Remember that I cannot rewrite the queries.

Comment: @PhilipKelley yes, that's the general idea. The problem is then to get a value from earlier in the sequence, without having to explicitly insert the CTE name in the "from" statement. As I wrote in the title, I don't know whether it's possible or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Her'es a vague outline of how I'd approach this. It makes a lot of assumptions, is missing key components, has not been debugged in any way, and is *completely* dependent on those queries you have no control over being "good" for hard-to-acertain values of good.

Assumption: a set of queries that looks something like this:

```
Level1Q:  select * from users where name=:param_user
Level2Q:  select * from projects where id=:param_id
Level3Q:  select * from details where id=:param_id
Level4Q:  <etc>
```

So, for a "level 3" query, you'd want to generate the following:

```
;WITH
   Level1Q as (select * from users where name=:param_user)
  ,Level2Q as (select * from projects where id=:param_id)
  ,Level3Q as (select * from details where id=:param_id)
 select * from Level3Q
```

This, or something much like it, should produce that query:

```
DECLARE
  @Command   nvarchar(max)
 ,@Query     nvarchar(max)
 ,@Loop      int
 ,@MaxDepth  int
 ,@CRLF      char(2) = char(13) + char(10)  --  Makes the dynamic code more legible

SET @Command = 'WITH'


--  Set @MaxDepth to the level you want to query at
SET @MaxDepth = 3
SET @Loop = 0

WHILE @Loop < @MaxDepth
 BEGIN
    SET @Loop = @Looop + 1

    --  Get the query for this level
    SET @Query = <next query>

    SET @Command = replace(@Command + @CRLF
                           + case @Loop when 1 then '  ' else ' ,' end
                           + 'Level<<@Loop>>Q as (' + @Query + ')'
     ,':param_user', <appropriate value)  --  Only used when @Loop = 1
     ,':param_id', 'Level<<@Loop>>Q.id')  --  This assumes the link to the prior query is always by a column named "id"
     ,'<<@Loop>>', @Loop)  --  Done last, as the prior replace added another <<@Loop>>

 END

--  Add the final pull
SET @Command = @Command + @CRLF + replace(' select * from Level<<@Loop>>Q', '<<@Loop>>', @Loop - 1)

--  The most important command, because debugging this mess will be a pain
PRINT @Command

--EXECUTE sp_executeSQL @Command
```

Comment: It's much more complicated than I would have wanted but might provide a solution. Thank you. I will try to implement it and see how it goes.

Comment: Anytime you have to write code to build the code you need at the time of execution, it will be a complex problem. Good luck!